# Cordova/Phonegap print via JavaScript inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, plugins, printing

I want to print a page (or some pages) from an iPad app I'm developing. The first thing the app does when launching is to load an external web site by this code:

```
window.location = https://*****.**;
```

It is from this external web site I now want to print some stuff (works great in Safari on iPad). Trying this simple code

```
window.print();
```

But it doesn't work i the wrapped web app by Cordova/Phonegap.

I know there's plugins for this > but those require the js/html code to be local to work, right?

Any suggestions how I can make printings available in my app? Any suggestion is very welcome, hopefully there's an easy way!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it was not answered so far and I came accross the same problem.

Load the page you are visiting via ajax into a local javascript variable and send this local variable containing the html you want to get printed to the print function of your print plugin.

***OR***

If you want to print the current page, just get the contents into a local variable and send it your print plugin.

https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-print

You can use jQuery $.ajax, XmlHttpRequest or anything you want to get the html string into a local variable.

Example Usage (jQuery required):

```
$.get('https://*****.**',function(html){
    window.app.print(data,
        function(){
            console.log('success');
        },
        function(){
            console.log('error');
        }
    );
});

***OR***

var html = $('body').html();
window.app.print(html,
    function(){
         console.log('success');
    },
    function(){
         console.log('error');
    }
);

window.app = window.app || {};
window.app.print = function(html,successCallback,errorCallback) {
    successCallback = successCallback|| function(){};
    errorCallback = errorCallback|| function(){};
    var type = "text/html";
    var title = "test.html";
    var fileContent = html;
    window.plugins.PrintPlugin.print(
        fileContent,
        successCallback,
        errorCallback,
        "",
        type,
        title
    );
};
```

Comment: Looks lite it can work =) Haven't tried it thougt, thanks for the suggestion!